# $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty u_na_n$ given that $(a_n)_n$ is dense in $[-A,A]$ and $(u_n)_n$ is decreasing

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

I am wondering if the following is true :

> Let $(u_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a decreasing sequence such
> that $u_n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \to \infty$.
> Let $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $(a_n)_n \in [-A,A]^{\mathbb{N}}$ is dense in $[-A, A]$ for some $A \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ then:  $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty u_na_n$$
> converge.

I am enable to find a counter exemple. But I've notice the following :

- If the sequence : $\sum_{k=0}^N a_k$ converge then it's bounded and maybe we can use an Abel transform to prove that it converges.
- When we take $a_n = \sin(n)$ (then $A = 1$) then it converges. We can use an Abel transform to prove it.

Comment: This is not true. You can rearrange the sequence $(a_n)_n$ such that you have many more positive terms than negative ones (roughly speaking), and then the series will diverge to $\infty$, provided that $\sum_n u_n =\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Possible answer too long for the comments:

Is this a counter example:  take $c_n$ to be the positive rationals ordered $$\frac{1}{1}, \frac{2}{1},\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{1},\frac{2}{2},\frac{1}{3}, \cdots .$$  The rational $n/1$ then arises at the position $n(n-1)/2 + 1$.  Now create $a_n$ by inserting each negative rational, taken in the same order, immediately after $c_{2^k}$.

This will increase the position index of $n/1$ in $\{a_n\}$ from $n(n-1)/2 + 1$ to something like $n(n-1)/2 + \log_2 (n(n-1)/2 + 1)$.  Now take $u_k$ as slowly decreasing, for instance $1/(\sqrt[3]{k})$.

I think then as you sum $u_k a_k$ you will have infinitely growing contributions from the positive rationals $n/1$, each divided by $\sqrt[3]{ n(n-1)/2 + \log_2 (n (n-1)/2 + 1)}$.  The sum will be offset by negative rationals, but arising so infrequently that the sum must still diverge.  Apologies for not formalising this;  please say if you think this it works.

---

If the requirement that $a_n$ be bounded I believe a similar approach can be taken.  Start with a complete sequence of the positive rational in the interval $[0,A]$.  Then add the negative ratioals, using the same sequence but include each positioned as the $1, 2, 2^2, 2^3, \cdots $ term.  Finally mix in the constant $A/2$ as every other element.  Thus if $r_n$ is a list of the positive rationals,
$$a_n = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}A/2 & \text{when } n= 2,4,6, \cdots \\
-r_k & \text{when } n = 1, 3, 5, 9, 17, 33, \cdots, 2^k+1, \cdots \\
r_k &\text{for other } n, n = 7, 11, 13, 15, 19, 21, 23 ,\cdots \end{array} \right.$$
and choose $p_n$ to be any slowly declining positive sequence with unbounded sum.
Define $$u_n = \left\{ \array{ p_{n/2} &\text{for even } n \\
u_{n+1} & \text{for odd n}}\right. $$
so that $\{u_n\} = p_1, p_1, p_2, p_2, \cdots $.  I believe then $\sum_n u_na_n $ is also unbounded.

Comment: I don't understand. $(a_n)_n$ is not bounded here right ? Because $(a_n)_n$ need to be dense in $[-A,A]$ for some positive $A$ so it should be bounded

Comment: $a_n$ is dense in $\mathbb R$ and so dense in any bounded sub interval.  But It is not bounded. Was that a requirement?

Comment: Oooops I thought I've written bounded in my post. I edit it, but I think that what you say works so keep it, it still gives a counter example in the unbounded case.

Comment: Tried to include a bounded example - very similar.  Let me know if you think it works OK.